# Using Maven, in which directory should I place the image files for my icons?

Tags: java, maven, icons

I'm thinking that I should put them in

```
C:\ProjectName\src\main\resources\com\company\projectname\icons
```

but I want to be sure that I'm using Maven's best practices.

Comment: Fine, but `src/main/resources/icons` would do too. Look in your favourite open-source java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources is as good a place as any.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Do I need the package declaration? Would it be better to put my icons in C:\ProjectName\src\main\resources\icons or maybe C:\ProjectName\src\main\resources\projectname\icons?

Comment: It's up to you. If you feel that they serve better in a sub-directory, use it. images or icons is also good, so that you can reference what you want. But by default, anything you put in resources will get put in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem here.  I search for almost half a day trying to get some help on this subject.  There is not much useful information on this subject.  I did some experiment on my end.  Still, I would wish more experienced expert's opinion.  Here is what I found out.

My project is maven, and I am using Tomcat 7.  Java 7, which may be irrelevant.

My directory layout (ignoring irrelevant ones) :

```
src
  main
      java
      resources
               images
                     mytest.gif
               META-INF
      webapp
            images
                  mytest.gif
            js
            WEB-INF
            *.jsp
```

If you look at the war file, the images in the resources directory is under
  WEB-INF/classes/images/mytest.gif; whereas, the images in the webapp directory is publically accessable simply as images/mytest.gif.

Since I use both servlet and JSP in my web application, the question is which location for the images directory is better? It looks that the webapp to be better because the JSP is good for view whereas the servlets are good for logic and model.  There is no way that you can access the images located in the resources directory from the JSP (possible if you go through the proxy of another servlet).  Images don't seem to contain secrets, so you should make them public.

Or you may keep both directories, one for images containing secrets and the other don't.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do. 
1) If you are going to load images using serveletContext then resources folder is the right one.Because whatever in the resources will end up in the WEB-INF.
2) If you want to load them directly by their path from the root of the War folder, then you will need the maven WAR plugin.